# Expecting your views on developing an app like "Agile Reply"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I have read many post indicating that we can't send sms on Missed Call, but i would like to know the reason behind that.

Also there was a app called "Agile reply" for iphone but i cant find that app in the app store actually.it seems that it has been removed from the app store

I would like to develop an app like sending sms on missed call / un answered call.that app needs to be posted on "App store".my app needs to run on iOS 4.0 and 5.0

Please share your view on developing app with this kind of functionality and its possibility

why this kind of app will be rejected.

Comment: That app was most likely removed for blatantly acting in a major way (texting some random person who's call you chose not to answer for pete's sake!) without user interaction or permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Agile Reply app](http://appshopper.com/blog/2011/02/25/agile-reply-lets-you-respond-to-missed-calls-quickly-with-text-messages/) didn't send texts automatically upon a missed or unanswered call -- it just allowed you to quickly compose a message to the last number that called.

If Apple have decided they're unhappy with this sort of app, that's the end of the story. They have their reason(s), and whatever you think of those reasons, they're the gatekeeper of the app store; their say is final. Of course it might be possible to develop something like this for jailbroken devices, but that's a different story.

As for the reason that Apple didn't like the Agile Reply app: the following two reasons seem  plausible to me (but are also just educated guesses on my behalf):

1) The app accessed private APIs

2) Apple thought that the app didn't offer anything new or worthy: they might have reasoned that it is easy enough to go into the built-in phone app, select the last (missed) call, and compose a message to that number, without the need for a custom app